# Not able to Post object from angular Service to web Api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to angular,I have made a application in visual studio 2017 using angular 6 and asp .net core 2.0.
I am not able to  Post object from angular Service to web API. Web API is working fine when I am calling it from an HTML Page using Ajax call, But fails to work 
when Post requested from angular Services.
I have used all the possible solutions, like changing HTTP header, applying  [FromBody] in Web api parameter  etc

Below is Code For PostRequest

```
createProduct(product): Observable<ProductModel> {
    const httpHeaders = this.httpUtils.getHTTPHeaders();  ///Format is     result.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
     return this.http.post<ProductModel>('http://localhost:25875/api/Product/Index' , product, { headers: httpHeaders });
}
```

Here is my controller code

```
 [Route("api/Product")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{

   [HttpPost]
    public string Index([FromBody]ProductModel Product)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Called Index");
        return "";
    }
}
```

[This is the link to Error that i am getting in my Console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz6AJ.png)

Comment: 404 means that the URL points to a resource that wasnt found. You are sending a request to `'http://localhost:25875/api/Product/Index'` but the route of that method in your controller is `'http://localhost:25875/api/Product'`.

Comment: If i am calling this same url  http://localhost:25875/api/Product/Index from my html page using ajax ,its getting hit, why not from the post request from angular service. @Jota.Toledo . I tried changing to what u said, but still the same issue.

Comment: can you add the output from the networks tab for both the faulty and the working requests?

Answer (score 0):

You are using attribute routing with the default `HttpPost` attribute but calling the action name in the request URL.

You would need to update the action to match the desired URL

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProductController : Controller {
    //POST api/product/index
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public string Index([FromBody]ProductModel Product) {    
        Debug.WriteLine("Called Index");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Using `HttpPost` without a route template is the same as calling

```
[HttpPost("")]
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
```

which would route to `POST api/product` without the action name. That is why you get `404 Not Found` when requesting `POST api/product/index`

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)